# Additivity of Elliptic Curve Rank over Compositum of Fields

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, l-functions, number-fields

Assume that BSD holds for number fields. Let $E/\mathbf{Q}$ be an elliptic curve. For simplicity, let's assume it has Mordell-Weil rank zero. Let $F_1/\mathbf{Q}$ and $F_2/\mathbf{Q}$ be finite, abelian, disjoint extensions, and let $F=F_1.F_2$ denote their compositum.

> **Question:** Under what conditions can we conclude that
> $$ \mathrm{rank}_{\mathbf{Z}}(E/F)=\mathrm{rank}_{\mathbf{Z}}(E/F_1) + \mathrm{rank}_{\mathbf{Z}}(E/F_2) ?$$
>
> In other words, are there any sufficient conditions to ensure that any Mordell-Weil rank growth in $F$ actually in arises either $F_1$ or $F_2$?

On the one hand, this seems too good to be true. On the other hand, *if we assume BSD for number fields*, it seems that we should be able to make an argument using the factorization of $L$-functions as follows:

Let $\mathrm{Gal}(F_1/\mathbf{Q})=G_1$ and $\mathrm{Gal}(F_2/\mathbf{Q})=G_2$. Since $F_1 \cap F_2 = \mathbf{Q}$, we have $\mathrm{Gal}(F/\mathbf{Q})=G_1 \times G_2$. Using $^\hat{}$ to denote character groups, it seems we should have
\begin{align*}
L(E, F, s) &= \prod_{\chi\in \hat{G}} L(E, \mathbf{Q}, s, \chi)\\ &\simeq \prod_{\chi_1\in \hat{G_1}}\prod_{\chi_2\in \hat{G_2}} L(E, \mathbf{Q}, s, \chi_1 \chi_2)\\ &=L(E, F_1, s)\times L(E, F_2, s) \times\prod_{\substack{\chi_1\in \hat{G_1} \\ \chi_1\neq 1}}\prod_{\substack{\chi_2\in \hat{G_2} \\ \chi_2\neq 1}} L(E, \mathbf{Q}, s, \chi_1 \chi_2)
\end{align*}
where the products are taken over the irreducible characters. Thus, we have the desired additivity if we can control the terms of the form $L(E, \mathbf{Q}, s, \chi_1 \chi_2)$.

Are there any hypotheses which push this across the finish line?

---

Edit: Ariel Weiss has posted an answer which highlights the following situation:
$$E=X_0(11), F_1=\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{-7}), F_1=\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{-8}), F=\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{-7},\sqrt{-8})$$ Then we have

$$\mathrm{rank}_{\mathbf{Z}}(E/\mathbf{Q})=0, \mathrm{rank}_{\mathbf{Z}}(E/F_1)=1, \mathrm{rank}_{\mathbf{Z}}(E/F_2)=1, \mathrm{rank}_{\mathbf{Z}}(E/F)=2$$ This is precisely the sort of situation I'm looking to capture in general.

Comment: I think you have an extra factor of $L(E, \mathbb Q, s)$ in your factorisation. (e.g. it goes wrong if $F_1 = \mathbb Q$)

Comment: There is little hope that this is true. The representation $\mathbb{C}\otimes E(F)$ of $G_1\times G_2$ can have all sorts of irreducible blocks. If the only irreducible pieces are coming from the characters that are trivial on one factor, you should expect the formula to be $rk E(F) = rk E(F_1) + rk E(F_2) - rk E(\mathbb{Q})$. Formulas like this linking the rank between subextensions are possible, due to Brauer relations for the group $G$, but only if $G$ is non-abelian.

Comment: One checks using Sage that the example suggested in Ariel Weiss's answer, with $E=X_0(11)$ and the quadratic extensions obtained by adjoining square roots of $-7$ and $-8$, provides precisely the sort of thing I'm looking for. Namely, the rank over each of $\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{-7})$ and $\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{-8})$ is 1, and the rank over the compositum is exactly 2. So I'm asking what makes this example work, even though there is no good reason to believe it works in general.

Comment: @JeffH I intended that to be more of a counterexample than an example, by replacing $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-7})$ with $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{56})$. What makes this work is exactly the fact that $\mathrm{rk}\ E(\mathbb Q(\sqrt{56}) = 0$.

Comment: @ArielWeiss Oh sure, I appreciate and understand that. It's an interesting example since it shows that, at least partially, an answer to my question depends on a matter of perspective, i.e. it matters what $F_1$ and $F_2$ are, and it is not enough to just look at $F$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're willing to expand your question a bit, there are interesting relations to be found. More precisely, let $E/K$ be an elliptic curve defined over a number field, and let $L/K$ be a Galois extension such that $G(L/K)$ has a non-trivial idempotent relation (also sometimes called a Brauer relation). For example, this will be true if if $G(L/K)$ is a non-cyclic abelian group. Each idempotent relation yields a corresponding relation among the ranks of $E(F)$ as $F$ ranges over the  fields lying between $K$ and $L$. This, and much more, may be found in the paper
*Kani, Ernst; Rosen, Michael*, [**Idempotent relations among arithmetic invariants attached to number fields and algebraic varieties**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1006/jnth.1994.1014), J. Number Theory 46, No. 2, 230-254 (1994). [ZBL0853.14011](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0853.14011).

Answer (score 6):

It's quite easy to find counterexamples.

For example, take an elliptic curve $E/\mathbb Q$ of rank 0, and choose two quadratic twists, $E_{d}, E_{d'}$ of rank 1. By root number considerations, $E_{dd'}$ has even rank, so it probably has rank $0$. For example, you could take $E = X_0(11)$, $d = -7$, $d' = -8$.

Then $E(\mathbb Q(\sqrt{dd'})$ has rank 0 and $E(\mathbb Q(\sqrt{d})$ has rank 1. But $E(\mathbb Q(\sqrt d, \sqrt{d'})$ has rank at least $2$, with the additional point of infinite order coming from $E(\mathbb Q(\sqrt{d'})$, which also has rank $1$.

In your BSD example, the L-function of $E$ over $\mathbb Q(\sqrt d, \sqrt{d'})$ factors as
$$L(E, s)L(E_d, s)L(E_{d'}, s)L(E_{dd'}, s),$$

Here, the extra $L$-factor $L(E, \mathbb Q, s, \chi_1\chi_2)$ is measuring the contribution to the rank from some other subextension of the compositum of $F_1$ and $F_2$.

This type of argument works more generally under your assumptions that $F_1, F_2$ are Galois. So somehow, your assumption needs to be that no other subextension of $F_1\cdot F_2$ contributes to the rank.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Right, I agree that this is an example of the sort of thing I'm trying to avoid. So essentially I'm looking for conditions which ensure that "no other subextension of $F_1.F_2$ contributes to the rank."

Comment: I think so. You can do all this without BSD. Let $\mathrm{Gal}(F/\mathbb Q)$ act on $V:= E(F)\otimes\mathbb C$. Then you can decompose $V$ as a direct sum $\oplus V_\chi$ over the isotypic components corresponding to the irreps of $G$. Some components will come from $G_1$ and $G_2$, but others will come from neither. It is these ones that you have to somehow control.

Comment: Ah, nice observation. That might turn out to be very useful for my intended purposes. Thanks for pointing this out!